# SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE where we need to write in our project in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, session-cookies, django-sessions

In django for expire a session after closing a browser where we need to type
`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` this in which file??

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py file

Please read the documentation of How to use sessions:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE